# Populate Scope Values from URL on Initial Load

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular so bear with me.
I have a controller that handles the search functionality within a page.
As a user changes the search the url changes to reflect the user interaction. Then there are $http.post calls to an API to retrieve those values within the URL. A repeater in a separate controller is updated appropriately.

This works great and the scope changes correctly.

But how do I handle initial load?

If a user clicks a saved search. 
Example:

http://blah/blah/blah/Search/Status-1%7CBeds-3

I would want the search fields and the scope to be set appropriately but then the same functionality should continue.

What is the best way of doing this?
If code is needed then ask, but this is more of a which direction to go question then a fix my code question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [AngularJS routing](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) and [the `$routeParams` object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams).

If that is not adequate, you can use [the $location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) to extract information from the URL and write it to the `$scope` in your [controller constructor function](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Comment: For my specific use case, i needed to access location and parse.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ui-router you can define the search string as a parameter that can be used when deep linking

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    })
    .state('search', {
        url: '/search/:searchtoken',
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchController'
    });
```

http://www.funnyant.com/angularjs-ui-router/

Comment: This wasn't applicable to my specific situation but i do see needing to use this technique in other areas of our application down the road.....

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to populate the search variable with the url params. Something like:

```
if params
  $scope.searchInputVal = params
  $scope.doPostRequest()
```

(sorry for the coffee script syntax)

and just ensure whatever function you have to update these search parameters is firing `onChange()` or `onClick()` whichever you're using to fire the post request to begin with.